# How to grow a Dracaena from a broken branch

Tags: dracaena

I accidentally broke one branch in a dracaena I have. I just put in another pot with some soil and it surprisingly start to root and grow. Issue is, it is very thin and disproportionate in respect to his own leaves. It does seems to grow in becoming thicker, are there some way to force it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wait, it is growing a root system now and a thicker stem will come later

Provide lots of light and go easy on the water. No fertilizer is required till next summer as it has no roots to absorb it

Comment: I usually start them in water and move to soil after a few months after they develop roots.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding this suggestion for others facing a similar dilemma: Root the branch in water - 1 week approx - then plant it back in the mother pot.